# Excel VBA Coding

Tags: excel, vba

I am new with VBA coding, could you help me towards this concern?

I am currently creating a macro which will search the specific text in the column AJ (e.g. "Chase") and if found, it will lookup for the entity from the column A and then copy paste it to other sheet.

[image]

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Maybe `VLOOKUP` function is what you are looking for!

Comment: Sub EachLoopExample()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet3")

For Each MyCell In ws1.Range("AE:AE")
    If MyCell.Value = "check" Then
        sResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("check", ws1.Cells("AE7:A2693"), 31).Select
        ws2.Range("A2").Selection.Value
    End If
    
Next MyCell

End Sub

Comment: But I am having an error with this. Error 1004.

Comment: @RCaetano Hi Sir, may you kindly advise what could be the better coding for this??

Comment: At first glance, if the code you posted is the full version I would say that at least you need to remove the `.Select` and then make `ws2.Range("A2").value = sResult`, but confirm first the code you posted please.

Comment: Hi sir, What do you mean by full version??

Comment: I am now having error of error 424: object required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Taken from the comments. Remember that the errors you might get is because of the VLookup formula. You need to look at how the VLookup formula is working.
`=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE).`

The formula is searching for "Check". The errors you get is in the range you are searching in, you are searching for "AE7:A2693" that is column AE to A - it is not possible to search backwards, so it should be A2693:AE7. You have to find the correct range and change it in the code below.
Are you sure that column 31 is containing the return value?

```
Sub EachLoopExample()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim sResult As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet3")
For Each MyCell In ws1.Range("AE:AE")
    If MyCell.Value = "check" Then

        sResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("check", ws1.Range("B1:C3"), 1, False)
        ws2.Range("A2").Value = sResult
    End If
Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Niclas, I manage to make the above coding work, thank you very much for your instructions and advise. However only 1 cell value can be lookup on the above coding. For example, if there are three cells that have value of "chase" in the column AK, only the first row would be copied in the designated sheet. May you kindly advise what could be changed in the above coding?

Comment: Could you please post the exact VLookup formula you are using, together with the data range. I am still not quite sure what you are trying to do. You want to insert this VLookup formula in Sheet3 (clean sheet to see the matches), but what do you have in Sheet1? AE is check, AK is chase?

Comment: Re-read your question. What you want is to look up e.g. "Chase" in column AJ and if it is found, you want it to return the value from column A (e.g. OC_81) in Sheet3 column A?

Comment: Hi Niclas, pls kindly refer my answer above :) thanks!

Comment: Hi Niclas, I already got the correct coding the only problem is that when the cells is blank, the macro do not capturing that and then jump to cell with values and paste it to the other sheet. And thus encountering because it would not align to its proper row. How could I mend this?

Comment: I don't understand why you changed from your original idea of using `VLookup`. I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve with the new code, since you do not have any comments in it. You should also avoid using `.select`. Try to explain what you want to do, then I am sure we can do it in a better way than having all these procedures.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub EachLoop()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim FinalRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set ws1 = Sheet1
Set ws2 = Sheet3

ws1.Select
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To FinalRow
    If Cells(i, 31) = "check" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Copy
        ws2.Select
        Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Select
    End If

Next i

ws2.Select

Range("B2").Select

Call EachLoop2

End Sub

Sub EachLoop2()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim FinalRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set ws1 = Sheet1
Set ws2 = Sheet3

ws1.Select
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To FinalRow
    If Cells(i, 32) = "check" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
        ws2.Select
        Range("H200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Select
    End If

Next i

ws2.Select

Range("B2").Select

Call EachLoop2_ext


End Sub

Sub EachLoop2_ext()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim FinalRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set ws1 = Sheet1
Set ws2 = Sheet3

ws2.Select
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To FinalRow
    If Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 13)) = "" Then
        ws2.Select
        Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 13)).ClearContents
        Range(Cells(i, 14), Cells(i, 20)).Cut
        Range("I200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Else
        ws2.Select
        Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 13)).ClearContents
        Range(Cells(i, 14), Cells(i, 20)).Cut
        Range("I200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    End If

Next i

ws2.Select

Range("I2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Niclas, I had already manage to make another code that would make my desired outcome. However, I am still having some error with the last coding for EachLoop2_ext(). Error 1004. Could you kindly check and take a look on this??

Comment: I just made different macro coding from the EachLoop because I don't know how to skip columns in range selection. Example in EachLoop2 : Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
What I really want is that it would only copy from Range(Cell(I,1) and then jump to Cell(i,8) to Cell(i,13).

Comment: Do you know the simpler coding for this?